# UIImage created from MTKView results in color/opacity differences

Tags: swift, uiimageview, metal, render-to-texture, metalkit

When I capture the contents of an MTKView into a UIImage, the resulting image looks qualitatively different, as shown below:

[image: MTKView vs UIImageView of the same]

The code I use to generate the UIImage is as follows:

```
let kciOptions = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!,
                         kCIContextOutputPremultiplied: true,
                         kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false] as [String : Any]
let lastDrawableDisplayed = self.currentDrawable! // needed to hold the last drawable presented to screen
drawingUIView.image = UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(mtlTexture: lastDrawableDisplayed.texture, options: kciOptions)!)
```

Since I don't modify the ciImage orientation (.oriented(CGImagePropertyOrientation.downMirrored)) the resulting image is upside down, as shown in the image above. I leave the mirrored orientation as is so I can point out the color differences between the two image captures.

No matter how I change the kciOptions parameters, (say, even changing the colorspace to grayscale) I'm not seeing any changes in the resulting UIImage, which appears much more dim/desaturated than the original. Does anybody have any suggestions for how I can accurately capture what I'm drawing on MTKView to an UIImage? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Below are my MTKView settings which may prove relevant:

```
let renderPipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
renderPipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = self.sampleCount
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha         renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha            renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha              renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
self.isOpaque = false // makes MTKView bg transparent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CGColorSpace` is `.sRGB` but your renderPipelineDescriptor's pixelFormat is `.bgra8Unorm`.  Try changing that line to:

```
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm_srgb
```

Comment: Thank you @hartw.  Your answer was very nearly the reason for the color difference.  After much heartache, I came to a subtle finding which I'll post below.  Thank you again

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this issue in a couple of posts, but no clear answer. Here is what I've found:

For starters,

```
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm
```

should really just be set to the MTKView's native pixel format

```
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = self.colorPixelFormat
```

Secondly, when I set the CIImage's options:

```
let kciOptions = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!,
                         kCIContextOutputPremultiplied: true,
                         kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false] as [String : Any]
```

It didn't matter what I set **kCIContextWorkingColorSpace** to, I never saw any visual difference regardless of what I used.  The property I really needed to set is called **KCIImageColorSpace**. So the updated kciOptions looks like:

```
let kciOptions = [kCIImageColorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                      kCIContextOutputPremultiplied: true,
                      kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false] as [String : Any]
```

In a similar way of using the view's native pixel format, calling CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB() creates an RGB colorspace that is specific to the device being used.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this!

Comment: Adding color space option did not work for me.  Also additg CIContextOption there is not allowed now.

Comment: Converting texture's format before getting CIImage worked for me. Like:
let tex = drawable!.texture.makeTextureView(pixelFormat: .bgra8Unorm_srgb)!

Comment: Thank you, I'm also building a drawing engine and all the questions you made have helped a lot

Answer (score 3):

```
let context = CIContext()
let texture = metalView.currentDrawable!.texture
let cImg = CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: nil)!
let cgImg = context.createCGImage(cImg, from: cImg.extent)!
let uiImg = UIImage(cgImage: cgImg)
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained why this code works, but thanks for contributing!